# Parameters in real time for query

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've a multistep form where, in the first step, users can choose a date. In the second step i would like to take the value of date (for a query that shows free time of that day). How can i pass this value, in real time, without refresh?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a request to the server and get a response without reloading the page, you can use ajax:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp